# unable to bind dataset value to label

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

While assigning `DataSet` value to `Label` getting 
`System.Data.DataRow` not exact data.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 text from tbl_HomepageContent where company = 'jagsar'", con);
//cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
lblHomepageContent.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
```

Comment: @krishnamohan - you determined the `Table` by index and the `Row` by index, now you have to select the correct column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `DataSet` for determining one value. `ExecuteScalar` produces less overhead

```
string Command = "select top 1 text from tbl_HomepageContent where company = @company";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, myConnection))
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@company", "jagsar"));
        lblHomepageContent.Text = (string)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```